# chrome extension - Cannot read property 'url' of undefined at Object.callback

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, callback

I am trying to access chrome.tabs in callback function

Here is the code:

```
chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {text: 'validatePage'}, fnValidatePage);

function fnValidatePage(respObj){

    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tabs){

        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
                code: 'var srcUrl = "' + tabs[0].url + '";'
        }, function() {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{file:'jquery-1.12.2.min.js'},function (){       
                if(tabs[0].url.indexOf('yellowpages.com') >= 0){
                    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{file:'yellowpages.js'});
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Getting the below Error:

```
Error in response to tabs.query TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined at Object.callback
```

what is going wrong and how do I get current tab url in the callback function?

manifest.json:

```
"permissions": [
     "tabs",
     "activeTab",
     "http://*/*",
     "https://*/*",
     "<all_urls>"
  ]
```

Comment: Did you check if `chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, ...` returns any tabs in the callback? Seems to me like your code is failing because there are no tabs found in the query, causing `tabs[0]` to be undefined.

Comment: tabs.length giving 0. SO, I changed like this [code] chrome.tabs.query({}, function(tabs) [/code] . Getting below error  [code]Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.executeScript: Cannot access contents of url[/code]

Comment: `ExecuteScript()` normally gets 3 parameters:  `chrome.tabs.executeScript(integer tabId, object details, function callback)`.  Have you tried to use the `tabId` (here: `tabs[0].id`) instead of `null`?  Furthermore you could surround the code inside `query()` by an `if(tabs[0].url)` check.